# SQL Joins and row links

Tags: sql

I have these two tables and my aim to only show the highest mark an individual has got in a certain code basis therefore and only display the name of the individual, taking the mark from a certain no row and linking that with the no row from the other table and displaying the name, code and no

Table 1

```
+----+------+------+
| no | code | mark |
+----+------+------+
| 01 | B4   |   90 |
| 02 | B5   |   50 |
| 03 | B4   |   50 |
+----+------+------+
```

Table 2

```
+----+------+------+
| no | name | numb |
+----+------+------+
| 01 | John | NULL |
| 02 | Mike | NULL |
| 03 | Jake | NULL |
+----+------+------+
```

---

```
SELECT table2.no, table2.name, table1.code
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table1
    WHERE code LIKE 'B4%'
    ORDER BY MAX(mark);
```

The main issue is that there doesn't seem to be a link between the code and the no from table 1.

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.no = table2.no` instead.

Comment: So if No 01 with code B4 and mark 95 also existed in table 1; would you want to display it instead of 90? is this even possible in your application?

Comment: @pieter-geerkens Thank you that helped alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to SQL as well but try this:

```
SELECT table2.no, table2.name, table1.code
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table1
    ON table1.no = table2.no
    WHERE code LIKE 'B4%'
    ORDER BY MAX(mark);
```

Comment: Thanks man, helped alot I was just missing the ON bit. Thanks